# New to coding: /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Tags: python-3.x, image, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am new to coding. I have just downloaded Python 3 and Anaconda; I am learning how to do the basics e.g. markup with an online course for beginners.

I am attempting to add an image to markup with:

```
![Image of bird](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/Eopsaltria_australis_-_Mogo_Campground.jpg/1024px-Eopsaltria_australis_-_Mogo_Campground.jpg)
```

but I get the following error

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

What is happening?

Nb. doing the following is successful for me:

```
from IPython.display import Image
```

from IPython.core.display import HTML
Image(url= "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/45/Eopsaltria_australis_-_Mogo_Campground.jpg/1024px-Eopsaltria_australis_-_Mogo_Campground.jpg")

Is it because I am on windows? I've encountered a few problems already, which seem to be due to using windows.

Comment: I guess you are using jupyter notebook: you forgot to change the cell type from code to markdown. You can do so from a dropdown menu in the navigation bar above.

Comment: I can't believe I made such a silly error. Thank you!
I imagine, therefore, that the second syntax works for cells whereas the first works for markdown?
Or does the second syntax work for both cells and markdown?